# Java Affine Transformations

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, affinetransform

I have a simple question to ask.

Is it possible to do an affine transform outside the paint/paintComponent context?
For instance, let's say i want to create a Shape made of a GeneralPath and then rotate it 45°.
Is it possible to create that object and then rotate it always in the class constructor instead of creating the object and then rotate it in the paint/paintComponent method?

Thank you very much.

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you very much for the info guys.
So today i have made a simple test as you suggested and it works.

This is with the Affine transform inside the paintComponent method, commented:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setColor(new Color(230, 230, 230));
    g2.fill(enne.getNuvola());//enne.getNuvola(): code from an omitted class. returns a Shape of a cloud
    g2.setColor(new Color(20, 20, 20));

    /*
    AffineTransform t = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(400,400);
    g2.transform(t);          
    */

    g2.fill(rock.getRocket());

}//paintComponent
```

and this is the affine transform inside the class constructor of a GeneralPath

```
public class Rocket {

GeneralPath rocket;

public Rocket(){

    rocket = new GeneralPath();
    rocket.moveTo(10,10);
    rocket.lineTo(15,15);
    rocket.lineTo(15,50);
    rocket.lineTo(5,50);
    rocket.lineTo(5,15);
    rocket.lineTo(10,10);
    rocket.closePath();

    AffineTransform t = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(400,400);
    rocket.transform(t);


}//Rocket Costruttore

public GeneralPath getRocket(){
    return this.rocket;
}

}//Rocket
```

But now i have another question:

Do i have to protect the current state of the current trasform also in the Rocket class like it is suggested to do for the paintComponent method in the [java transforming tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)?

1. Use the getTransform method to get the current transform.
2. Use transform, translate, scale, shear, or rotate to concatenate a transform.
3. Perform the rendering.
4. Restore the original transform using the setTransform method.

Again, thank you very much for your answers [image: :-)]

Comment: I second what @AndrewThompson says. It's indeed possible. Why not give it a try?

Comment: It's a particularly instructive exercise; use the `Shape`'s `PathIterator` to see the effect.

Comment: yes, just draw and rotate the image in a transparent buffereimage and draw it whenever you want, or also create a class and extent JComponent, override the paint method and do the same, the second one would add as component to forms too

Answer (score 1):

No, the transform should be reset only to restore the state of the Graphics object, because that Graphics object could be reused by the system for other drawings. If you do the transform without a Graphics object, you don't need to worry about that.

Note for the future that you should not ask new questions by editing old questions, because this is confusing. You should post a completely new question (possibly linking your old question).

Comment: Thank you very much.
And thank you very much also for the editing/answering tips.